# Consultar BD cada determinado tiempo sin necesidad de refrescar la página

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Necesito ayuda, tengo una tabla la cual hace una consulta muy simple de ciertos datos al xampp pero al guardar la info en el formulario no se muestra en la tabla sino hasta que actualizo la página. Habrá una manera de visualizar los datos que se esten ingresando sin necesidad de estar actualizando toda la página? no tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo, mi codigo es asi

```html
<?php 
$conexion = mysqli_connect('','','')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
$consulta="SELECT * FROM tabla";
$execute = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
?>

<!html>
<table>
  <?php while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['peso'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['talla'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['edad'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
</table>
```

Esa consulta me arroja todos los datos en lista que tenga guardados pero no se actualiza si guardo al momento desde otro form

Comment: estudia sobre websockets

Answer (score 0):

EL problema es que con php y mysql solos no puedes hacer lo que quieres, pudes estudiar sobre websockets o de otra forma hacer el archivo php que hace las consultas a parte y usar `ajax` con javascript para hacer peticiones asincronas.

```
 <?php 
      /*archivo.php*/
      $conexion = mysqli_connect('','','')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
      $consulta="SELECT * FROM tabla";
      $execute = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
      // Crear un array asociativo con los datos
      $datos = array();
      while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){
        $datos[] = $row;
      }
      // Devolver los datos en formato JSON
      echo json_encode($datos);
 ?>
```

```html
<!html>
<head>
  <!-- Incluir jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Botón para actualizar la tabla -->
  <button id="actualizar">Actualizar</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Peso</th>
        <th>Talla</th>
        <th>Edad</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cuerpo">
      <!-- Aquí se mostrarán los datos de la tabla -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    // Función para actualizar la tabla
    function actualizarTabla(){
      // Hacer una petición AJAX al archivo PHP
      $.ajax({
        url: "archivo.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(datos){
          // Vaciar el cuerpo de la tabla
          $("#cuerpo").empty();
          // Recorrer el array de datos
          $.each(datos, function(i, dato){
            // Crear una fila con los datos
            var fila = "<tr><td>" + dato.peso + "</td><td>" + dato.talla + "</td><td>" + dato.edad + "</td></tr>";
            // Agregar la fila al cuerpo de la tabla
            $("#cuerpo").append(fila);
          });
        },
        error: function(error){
          // Mostrar algún mensaje de error
          alert("Ha ocurrido un error al obtener los datos");
        }
      });
    }

    // Asignar el evento click al botón actualizar
    $("#actualizar").click(actualizarTabla);

    // Llamar a la función al cargar la página
    $(document).ready(actualizarTabla);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ese es un ejemplo sencillo de como seria de este metodo.